# Is there a way to integrate a see more function into Python web scraper?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am building a custom web scraper for a Russian news site, RIA.ru. After a search, the site displays the first 20 relevant articles. To see additional articles, you have to click the blue button at the bottom that says "see more."

Here is an example searching for McDonalds: https://ria.ru/search/?query=mcdonalds. There are 293 hits, but only the first 20 display.

My web scraper currently only evaluates the first 20 hits. I would like it to evaluate all the hits.

I identified the html attribute for and relative link for the "see more" button: /services/search/getmore/?query=mcdonalds&offset=20

I figured I could program the scraper to find that link and paste it onto the absolute link. I could then pull HTML from that page and repeat the process until no more "see more" links turn up. Then I would scrape the page for the content links.

I tried to paste it together with the absolute link, but it does not work. I also tried to paste it together with multiple variations of the absolute link. That also failed.

Does anyone have other suggestions? I really want the scraper to scrape all relevant articles.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

query = "mcdonalds"
searchURL = "https://ria.ru/search/?query="

# Create starting link

searchURL = searchURL + query

# Create list for the "see more" links or scroll links

scrollLinks = []

# Pull the HTML from the starting link and clean it

html = urlopen(searchURL)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Find the "see more links" (there will only be one)
# Append the relative link to the list

for link in bsObj.findAll("div", {"class":"list-more"}):
    if 'data-url' in link.attrs:
        scrollLinks.append(link.attrs['data-url'])

# Paste relative link onto master link

searchURL = searchURL + scrollLinks[0]        

# Print it

print(searchURL)
```

The print returns this:

https://ria.ru/search/?query=mcdonalds/services/search/getmore/?query=mcdonalds&offset=20

The link does not take you to the same page but with 20 additional articles present. Instead, it just takes you to a new search page with nothing returned.

Thanks for any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.However the url a bit different.Try the below code it will give you all 293 links.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = "https://ria.ru/services/search/getmore/?query=mcdonalds&offset={}"
page_num = 0
session = requests.Session()
totalurls=[]
while True:
    pageTree = session.get(page.format(page_num))
    pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')
    items = pageSoup.find_all(class_='list-item__title color-font-hover-only')
    for item in items:
        title = 'https://ria.ru' + item['href']
        totalurls.append(title)

    if page_num<280:
      page_num += 20
      page = "https://ria.ru/services/search/getmore/?query=mcdonalds&offset={}".format(page_num)

    else:
     break
print(totalurls)
print(len(totalurls))
```

Output:

```
['https://ria.ru/20190826/1557929866.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190813/1557454474.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190731/1557057024.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190725/1556861008.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190709/1556333622.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190705/1556244317.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190530/1555087647.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190524/1554867334.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190325/1552073318.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190226/1551353147.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190116/1549459263.html', 'https://ria.ru/20190116/1549412375.html', 'https://ria.ru/20181115/1532878009.html', 'https://ria.ru/20180927/1529462687.html', 'https://ria.ru/20180807/1526108337.html', 'https://ria.ru/20180715/1524622093.html', 'https://ria.ru/20180713/1524496100.html', 'https://ria.ru/20180615/1522774167.html', 'https://ria.ru/20180413/1518548132.html', 'https://ria.ru/20180309/1516048056.html', 'https://ria.ru/20180308/1516015678.html', 'https://ria.ru/20180216/1514738698.html', 'https://ria.ru/20171229/1511932214.html', 'https://ria.ru/20171204/1510139734.html', 'https://ria.ru/20171128/1509722443.html', 'https://ria.ru/20171124/1509514846.html', 'https://ria.ru/20171124/1509511458.html', 'https://ria.ru/20171124/1509502710.html', 'https://ria.ru/20171009/1506485704.html', 'https://ria.ru/20171008/1506419524.html', 'https://ria.ru/20171004/1506192303.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170726/1499223416.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170713/1498442822.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170629/1497541393.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170525/1495080187.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170421/1492771586.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170213/1487839022.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170131/1486896948.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170127/1486587582.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170124/1486393620.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170123/1486313060.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170116/1485785336.html', 'https://ria.ru/20170102/1485094363.html', 'https://ria.ru/20161205/1482860000.html', 'https://ria.ru/20161021/1479772967.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160919/1477278410.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160907/1476293662.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160906/1476210212.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160903/1476019972.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160827/1475429667.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160826/1475373426.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160726/1472918364.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160726/1472850539.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160722/1472659487.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160718/1470131278.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160629/1454264650.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160609/1444947015.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160607/1444079065.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160526/1439820521.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160506/1427762622.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160429/1423568431.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160426/1420428569.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160419/1415294726.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160419/1415286466.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160406/1403422141.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160405/1402992346.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160325/1396814834.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160217/1376254437.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160217/1376022088.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160128/1366422549.html', 'https://ria.rumcdonalds_test_21082014', 'https://ria.ru/20160122/1363167924.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160121/1362966735.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160118/1361194870.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160108/1356326189.html', 'https://ria.ru/20160105/1354929056.html', 'https://ria.ru/20151203/1335032519.html', 'https://ria.ru/20151119/1324198351.html', 'https://ria.ru/20151118/1323339489.html', 'https://ria.ru/20151110/1317603894.html', 'https://ria.ru/20151005/1297244505.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150923/1276669479.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150918/1260508315.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150915/1252513717.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150721/1139167761.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150609/1069120663.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150609/1069116460.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150609/1069116207.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150609/1069105531.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150523/1066108020.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150519/1065403513.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150508/1063447756.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150507/1063061937.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150425/1060823959.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150422/1060317282.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150416/1058953034.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150416/1058899766.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150410/1057759741.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150330/1055545046.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150330/1055537612.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150301/1050235346.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150211/404309142.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150129/1044824124.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150129/1044807897.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150128/1044621620.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150119/1043228041.html', 'https://ria.ru/20150115/1042630640.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141231/1041076251.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141218/1038913083.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141210/1037474159.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141209/1037317375.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141204/1036663305.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141204/1036589146.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141203/1036334610.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141201/1035919557.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141126/1035272511.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141120/1034253363.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141119/1034088224.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141119/1034083777.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141119/1034069303.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141110/1032538539.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141107/1032198324.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141105/1031822422.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141105/1031725080.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141021/1029382826.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141020/1029158069.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141013/1028104346.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141010/1027790390.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141010/1027779076.html', 'https://ria.ru/20141006/1027122272.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140927/1025881148.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140925/1025526489.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140924/1025437794.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140923/1025208023.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140919/1024761536.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140919/1024741767.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140916/1024249036.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140915/1024213351.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140915/1024153439.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140911/1023592125.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140910/1023498530.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140910/1023462119.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140909/1023438029.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140909/1023424789.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140909/1023419565.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140908/1023183339.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140905/1022823133.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140901/1022243244.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140827/1021607843.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140826/1021505034.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140826/1021455513.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140826/1021436007.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140825/1021369393.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140822/1021058416.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140822/1020987865.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140822/1020964610.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140821/1020887853.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140821/1020878656.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140821/1020876692.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140821/1020867008.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140821/1020863940.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140821/1020854238.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140821/1020846535.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140820/1020755523.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140814/1019963562.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140812/1019790161.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140808/1019359919.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140801/1018415663.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140728/1017895546.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140725/1017566553.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140725/1017487989.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140714/1015943776.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140521/1008709753.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140415/1003950998.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140411/1003540945.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140406/1002692823.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140404/1002591126.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140404/1002541310.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140404/1002479509.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140404/1002459449.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140403/1002438427.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140326/1001101674.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140318/999986852.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140228/997472636.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140218/995631669.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140213/994620069.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140212/994497954.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140208/993809357.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140207/993554934.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140123/990874996.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140120/990259320.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140109/988352775.html', 'https://ria.ru/20140107/988130239.html', 'https://ria.ru/20131216/984292484.html', 'https://ria.ru/20131213/983793399.html', 'https://ria.ru/20131206/982179184.html', 'https://ria.ru/20131022/971667590.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130930/966660132.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130918/963880857.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130910/962145221.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130816/956692403.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130807/954885316.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130729/952722733.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130727/952523372.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130724/951688973.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130723/951449293.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130722/951366845.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130719/950882788.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130717/950194937.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130712/949340545.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130708/948230143.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130704/947666328.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130703/947379118.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130703/947376811.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130613/943070180.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130602/227584536.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130524/939163443.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130522/938731579.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130419/933444177.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130226/924621668.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130222/924128283.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130221/924100340.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130221/924035653.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130218/923493755.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130218/923426433.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130218/399685402.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130214/922885267.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130206/921532007.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130122/919205807.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130121/918967161.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130114/917996449.html', 'https://ria.ru/20130105/498724656.html', 'https://ria.ru/20121227/916455094.html', 'https://ria.ru/20121120/911409408.html', 'https://ria.ru/20121031/908117878.html', 'https://ria.ru/20121023/905943636.html', 'https://ria.ru/20121003/765431403.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120914/750008368.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120802/714683043.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120727/710669962.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120727/710657921.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120724/707896252.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120719/703688980.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120711/696825952.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120530/498079182.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120514/497841033.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120501/639036285.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120418/628780017.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120411/622855803.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120411/622776966.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120410/622272612.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120322/602471965.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120322/602405399.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120302/225896118.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120124/547776570.html', 'https://ria.ru/20120124/547765730.html', 'https://ria.ru/20111108/483773728.html', 'https://ria.ru/20111019/463924464.html', 'https://ria.ru/20110825/423396692.html', 'https://ria.ru/20110727/407772160.html', 'https://ria.ru/20110510/372497368.html', 'https://ria.ru/20110310/344324110.html', 'https://ria.ru/20110308/343661709.html', 'https://ria.ru/20110302/341160103.html', 'https://ria.ru/20110201/329110632.html', 'https://ria.ru/20101228/314598889.html', 'https://ria.ru/20101128/301971744.html', 'https://ria.ru/20101123/299927644.html', 'https://ria.ru/20101104/292612796.html', 'https://ria.ru/20100615/246572422.html', 'https://ria.ru/20100522/237367766.html', 'https://ria.ru/20100415/222547983.html', 'https://ria.ru/20100131/830773457.html', 'https://ria.ru/20100122/205753955.html', 'https://ria.ru/20091109/192674241.html', 'https://ria.ru/20090507/170216295.html', 'https://ria.ru/20081227/158180838.html', 'https://ria.ru/20081209/156836138.html', 'https://ria.ru/20080504/106527628.html', 'https://ria.ru/20080309/101011380.html', 'https://ria.ru/20080309/101006325.html', 'https://ria.ru/20080223/99935006.html', 'https://ria.ru/20070411/63481432.html', 'https://ria.ru/20061219/57246357.html', 'https://ria.ru/20060503/47140916.html', 'https://ria.ru/20060424/46858404.html', 'https://ria.ru/20060421/46774284.html', 'https://ria.ru/20050909/41344205.html', 'https://ria.ru/20040519/593079.html', 'https://ria.ru/20040519/593054.html', 'https://ria.ru/20040519/592754.html', 'https://ria.ru/20020918/227555.html', 'https://ria.ru/20020918/227261.html']
293
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I will post the solution for anyone who is curious.

I studied the site behavior and found that adding &offset=20 to the base URL (https://ria.ru/search/?query=mcdonalds) to make https://ria.ru/search/?query=mcdonalds&offset=20 would display results 21 through 40.

https://ria.ru/search/?query=mcdonalds&offset=40 displays results 41-60 and so on.

Now I had a pattern.

First, I needed to determine how many total results a search returned and save it as an integer.

```
totalHits = (bsObj.find("div", {"class":"rubric-count m-active"}).get_text())
totalHits = int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", totalHits))     
print("There are " + str(totalHits) + " hits for that key word combination.")
```

Then, based on this number, I needed to find the number of cycles to go through. I divided the number of total hits by twenty and rounded up to get this.

```
cycles = math.ceil(totalHits/20) 
print("This will take " + str(cycles) + " cycles.")
```

Finally, I used a while statement to cycle through the search links and collect article URLs.

```
while cycles > 0:

    # Collect page links from that cycle

    for link in bsObj.findAll("span"):
        if 'data-url' in link.attrs:
            links.append(link.attrs['data-url'])

    # Update search link and collect HTML for it

    searchURL = searchURL + "&offset=" + str(counter)
    html = urlopen(searchURL)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

    counter = counter + 20
    cycles = cycles - 1


print(links)
print(len(links))
```

This returned a list of 293 links!